# Does form.submit() post checkbox data differently from standard submit button?

Tags: javascript, php, forms, codeigniter, submit

I just ran into an odd issue with my CodeIgniter app. I'm using a jQuery `.on('submit')` event handler to catch all form submissions and follows this procedure: grab the form object using `this`, stores the object for later, checks the user is logged in with an AJAX call, if logged in, gets the stored jQuery form object and submits the form with `form.submit()`.

This works absolutely fine for all my forms (form validation works fine, returns validation errors correctly) except when I have a `form` with a `checkbox`. The checkbox is just ignored.

I use a `required` form validation rule to make sure the user ticks the checkbox before continuing and it works absolutely fine when this event handler is disabled however, the validation error only appears (oddly) when I add another `input` to the form that isn't a `checkbox`!

I'm wondering if there's someone that can understand the theory behind why this error is happening? I could post the code but I'm about 90% sure this is something to do with the way that JavaScript handles posting of checkbox data that I'm just not aware of.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't use codeignitor but a checkbox only appears in post data when it is checked.

Comment: That's absolutely correct, however when a validation rule contains "required", it always returns an error stating that that particular element is required if nothing is posted. Works perfectly if I don't use the event handler.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript, by itself, doesn't actually post any form data.

In the standard HTML submit, if a checkbox is *not* checked, then there is no key/value submitted for that item.

I've learned the hard way that many Javascript form serializers (used by Ajax calls) are simply broken and don't follow the standards... I spend several days writing my own and my `Qunit` tests are almost longer than the code itself.

What you'll need to do is use your debugging tools (Firefox or Chrome) and watch the network tab -- see exactly what is submitted.

Comment: Just wanted to check, I may not have been 100% clear - I am not actually using an AJAX call to submit this form, it's being told to submit the standard way using form.submit() - is that still submitting a slightly different way? I know you said JS doesn't post the form data but is it handling the POST data differently than the browser would by default?
Also, I did check Safari's dev tools and oddly, only the csrf token is being submitted and not the submit button (which IS when not using javascript.. if that made sense!)

Comment: You mentioned `Ajax` in your original question so I had assumed.  Calling `form.submit()` should be *almost* the same as pressing the submit button -- the only difference being that no value for the submit button is passed down, since, well, there was no submit button.   (It's possible to have more than one submit button, and only the button that was used gets sent.)

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought! It's just confusing because regardless of whether I press submit or use form.submit(), no post data gets sent for the checkbox element. This leads me to believe that CI's form validation uses the submit button's value to detect whether or not to run the form validation. I'm going to check the core files and see if that is indeed the problem. The only solution for now is sadly to not use the event handler for this particular form which is a shame because it's a really nice feature of my app.

Comment: Think I just realized the problem - if the POST array is empty, CI won't run validation. That explains why it works when I add another random form element. And the POST array is empty because using form.submit() isn't posting the button as you mentioned.

Comment: You might be on to something -- I don't use `CI` myself.  Sounds like you can just add a dummy hidden field then to fill things out.

Comment: Indeed. Although, it is a mystery why the POST array is empty when the hidden CSRF field is definitely still being posted. Looks like some further investigation is going to be required.

Answer (score 0):

With very helpful advice from Jeremy J Starcher, I worked out the problem. CodeIgniter's form validation was not running since the $_POST array was empty. Usually, even with only one input field (a checkbox) the actual submit button's value is POSTed, therefore even if the checkbox isn't checked and no value for it is posted, the $_POST array is still populated by the submit button's value. However, when using Javascript to submit the form, the submit button's value is ignored and not POSTed (thanks to Jeremy for that vital info).

The solution was to add a blank, hidden input field (of a type that is always POSTed, regardless of value). There may be a nicer way to solve this using Javascript to create a blank POST variable or something and I welcome further answers relating to this.

As a side note, I was confused as to how CSRF validation was succeeding and yet the $_POST array was empty - I checked out CodeIgniter's Security Class and basically it checks the CSRF POST variable and if it's all good, it unsets it, so by the time the $_POST array was hitting the Form Validation Class, it *was* empty.